# How can I combine these three find commands into one?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I like to have every file I might want one keybinding away. Currently I have a shell script with these three find commands that I pipe into fzf. But for a variety of reasons I need to combine them into one command (not the least because my current approach is ugly and I am sure flawed).

```
find ~  \! \( -path */.git/* \) -type d

find ~  \(  -iname \*.Rmd -o -iname \*.el \)  -a \! \( -iname index.txt  -o -path */.thunderbird/* -o -path */python3.8/*  -o -path */.git/* \) -type f

find ~ -regextype posix-extended \( -not  -regex ".*/\.sw(o|p)" -a -not -regex ".*\~$"  \)   -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

If anyone would like to critisize my ugly find commands and suggest a more efficient/clean way of whitelisting/blacklisting file extensions -- I would be grateful.

**EDIT**
I have simplified the commands to make it easier to understand their function.

- The first command looks for directories under the home path `~` but excludes `.git` directories and their subdirectories.
- The second command finds files in the home directory specifying whitelisted file extensions and then blacklisted file extensions and paths.
- The third finds dotfiles in my home directory `~` but excludes certain regexs.

Comment: what is the intended function of each of the commands?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have updated the post to answer this question and avoid unnessary complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
LC_ALL=C find ~/.                 \
  '('                             \
     -name .git -o                \
     -name .thunderbird -o        \
     -name python3.8              \
  ')' -prune -o                   \
  '('                             \
     -type d -o                   \
     '('                          \
        -name '*.[rR][mM][dD]' -o \
        -name '*.[eE][lL]' -o     \
          ! -path '*/./*/*'       \
          ! -name '.sw[op]'       \
          ! -name '*~'            \
     ')'                          \
     -type f                      \
  ')' -print
```

(here using standard `find` syntax (avoiding the `-regex`, `-regex-type`, `-iname`, `-maxdepth`, `-not`, `-maxdepth` which are all GNU extensions)).

Note that the `-prune` will globally skip all the `.git`/`.thunderbird`/`python3.8` directories, `find` will not even both looking into them. That will make a difference compared to your first `find` command which still prints the `.thunderbird` and `python3.8` directories, and the ones found within.

To be able to report the files at depth 1 (as with the `-maxdepth 1` of your third command), we append `/.` to the search dir, and exclude the files whose path matches `*/./*/*` (more than 2 levels below `/./`). That means however that paths will be printed as `/home/you/./file.txt`. If you don't like that `/./`, you can always get rid of it by piping the output to `| sed 's|/\./||;1s|/\.$//'`.

Note that your `! -iname index.txt` is redundant, as `index.txt` won't match `-iname \*.Rmd -o -iname \*.el` anyway. You also forgot the quotes around `*/.git/*` which could get expanded by the shell.

You may also want to replace the `-print` with `-print0` and use `fzf --read0` so it also works on file paths that contain newline characters.

Comment: What is the "LC_ALL=C" doing in this command?

Comment: @jds, with GNU `find` (and probably a few others), since `-name '*.txt'` matches on _any number of **characters**_ (`*`) followed by `.txt`, if we want it to match on anything that ends in `.txt`, we need to be in a locale where any sequence of bytes form valid characters. The `C` / `POSIX` locale is one of those (it's also the only one you're guaranteed to find on any system). You'll find that `find . -name '*'` doesn't match on the file created with  `touch $'St\xe9phane.txt'` if you're in a UTF-8 locale (where that `$'St\xe9phane'` is Stéphane encoded in iso8859-1 instead of UTF-8)

Comment: (continued) so I've gotten used to using `LC_ALL=C` whenever I use `find` with a name or path pattern, especially when missing files could have some bad consequences. In your case it would be problematic for `! -path '*/./*/*'` as that would mean that `/home/you/./dir/other/dir/di<0x80>rectory/some-file.with-wrong-extension` would not be excluded. You may not want to use `LC_ALL=C` when the patterns themselves contain non-ASCII characters (especially with the non-standard `-iname`/`-ipath`...) or when you want an exact count of *characters* in the locale's encoding.

Comment: See also [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372)